# O365 Skype for Business Admin User list not displaying all domain users

Tags: skype-for-business-2016, exchange-hybrid

We recently finished migrating on-prem exchange 2010 mailboxes to O365 in a hybrid environment (still existing) and are now exploring O365 functionality, including Skype.

Half of the company is listed in https://admin3a.online.lync.com/LSCP/Users.aspx post this migration without any explicit action I (sysadmin) knowingly performed.

I have added a SIP address in Exchange e-mail address to one user that is a priority to allow to login under Skype for Business, even though a number of other users don't have this alias, which didn't result in them being added to the above webpages user list after 24 hours.

The account I am logged into when visiting the above URL is a global admin, but I don't see the `Enable users` button in the above pages interface I have read on other posts can be used to enable Skype for other AD users in O365.

Clearly I am missing something; Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, “there is cs* and rts* groups that are needed to be members of to provide access to the Enable Users button” this is for Skype for business on premise, and for SFB Online you didn’t need to enable users, you just need to assign license.
Or could you please provide the screenshot for your question?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-skype-for-business-online/set-up-skype-for-business-online

Comment: This is O365, not on-prem, and with subsequent research those having rts* *attributes* aren't going to appear in O365 Skype for Business admin center anyways. Have checked and the users not appearing in O365 Skype for Business admin center don't have the rts* attributes. All users have the same license, both in Skype for Business admin center, and not. All were migrated through the hybrid setup we still have in place (I notice that if a new user is added in O365 (and same license applied) they get added to Skype for Business admin center, but am not going to remove and recreate 50 users and...

Comment: ... their mailboxes just to solve this issue (There has to be a simpler fix)). Not sure the need for a screenshot; The problem is simple. You can see some users in Skype for Business admin center using the link I previously provided (if you are on O365 you can go there and see what the interface looks like), and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no “enable users” in SFB admin center. 
I need to confirm if there is no SFB on-premises server.
I also test in my lab, create a new ad users and add sip address to his proxyAddress, force AAD sync, then assign license to this synced user, he appears as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming you don't see an `Enable users` button in O365 SFB. Alas your experience is not the same as mine. I tried the same thing and didn't get the user added to O365 SFB admin center.

Answer (score 0):

Not “you don't see an Enable users button in O365 SFB”, there is no “enable users” in SFB admin center, this is expect result and by design.
For your issue, New Office 365 users are not provisioned for Skype for Business Online, please follow these steps:

1. Make sure that the user has a valid Skype for Business Online license in the Office 365 portal and that the sign-in status of the user is set to Allowed.
2. After you've assigned an appropriate Skype for Business Online license, wait approximately 30 minutes, and then determine whether the user can sign in to Skype for Business Online through any Lync 2013 or Skype for Business client.
3. Whereas the service typically takes less than 30 minutes to provision a user, it can sometimes take up to 24 hours to fully provision a user for all services in Office 365. Therefore, wait 24 hours before you escalate the issue.
4. Are you synchronizing from an on-premises Active Directory organization, and was the user's msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress attribute already populated through a Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) domain that hasn't been verified by Office 365? In this situation, the user won't be provisioned in Skype for Business Online. If the issue persists, submit a support service request.